# Internet connection suddenly stops on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, internet

I'm having a problem with the internet on Ubuntu 16.04.

When I start my PC it automatically connects to the WiFi and everything works but after about 3 minutes the internet suddenly stops working even tough I am still connected to the WiFi.

Does anyone know what may be the problem here?

Here's a part of the syslog:

https://pastebin.com/WBnC0bBe

The internet stopped working at about 14:20.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems your wlan driver isn't working correctly: `wlxd0df9a9fd80a: Association request to the driver failed`

Comment: I've never installed a wlan driver. Do you think installing the driver might help?

Comment: Your networks "I bims das WLAN" and "FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7390" contain spaces and special characters. Does the Internet work properly if you connect to a wifi network without spaces and special characters in the name?

Comment: any updates on this please ?